# How can I increase username length of PhpMyAdmin/mysql user account?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I increase username length of PhpMyAdmin/mysql user account?

**Edit** : 
Sorry for my mistake. Its PhpMyAdmin/mysql user account not any mysql table.

**Answer** : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html
According to this article I should not do this.

Comment: Are you talking about `username` columns in your tables, or MySQL user account names? *Edit:* phpMyAdmin is just a frontend to MySQL. My question still stands.

Comment: executing the alter query in PHPMySQL should get your work done

Comment: Then none of the three answers are what you're looking for.

Comment: Ya.. It was my mistake in question title.

Comment: @dogbane: You should undelete your answer, yours was spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(2000);
```

refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

---

If it's MySQL's User table, then login as root

```
mysql --user=root mysql -pPASSWORD
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY user CHAR(100);
commit;
```

**THE ABOVE IS *NOT* RECOMMENDED**

Thanks for the feedback. I have tried the above, and column `user` could be changed successfully. However, MySQL manual warns against it

> MySQL user names can be up to 16 characters long. Changing the maximum length is not supported. If you try to change it, for example by changing the length of the User column in the mysql database tables, this will result in unpredictable behavior. (Altering privilege tables is not supported in any case.) Operating system user names might have a different maximum length. For example, Unix user names typically are limited to eight characters.

refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html

Thanks @BoltClock for mentioning it.

Comment: it mysql user account's username, not for any table.

Comment: While this may work, it's generally not a good idea to mess with system tables. But do what you must.

Comment: @BoltClock : Then isn't there any way to do this?

Comment: @Gaurav: Someone posted an answer (now deleted) that links to [this man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html). You may want to look at it.

Comment: @BoltClock : It mean can not do it.

Comment: Why on Earth did they limit it to 16 characters? So lame!